# In Android Studio how can i download image use URL which is reqiure login with Jsoup?

Tags: android, image, authentication, download, jsoup

I need a code for downloading image from url  with Jsoup which is require login.

```
           conn = Jsoup.connect(loginurl).data("username", username).data("password", password).data("LogIn", "").method(Connection.Method.POST).execute();
           loginCookies = conn.cookies();
           doc1 = Jsoup.connect("https://lorem.com").cookies(loginCookies).get();T
```

This is my code, it takes cookies with jsoup for use in Http connection. I've looked everywhere for a solution and tried everyting I've found in internet but it still not working.

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to download images or even GIFs.
In your `MainActivity.java` put this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Glide.with(this).load("https://your-image.png").into(imageView);
    }
```

Use this `implementation` in your `build.gradle(Module:app)`:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
}
```

And in the other `build.gradle(Project:app)` folder:

```
repositories {
  google()
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: I know this and also i use picasso but i want to load image from my account in the website . Website require login credentials for reach this photos.